# Bootstrap 4: own arrow in custom select menu

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, svg, icons, icon-fonts

I'm using the custom select menu (https://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/components/forms/#select-menu).

Now I want to change the arrows on the right.
I saw, that the class uses an background image to display the arrow.
But it's an strange url/svg...

Is there any way to change that image with an icon from a font?
Or at least with an other svg?